# Is it possible to disable mobile touch on a Salesforce community

Tags: community, mobile, locker-service, fullcalendar

**Background**

I have a community page which displays a calendar by [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/)

The calendar is in a Lightning Component.

Both Salesforce Communities and FullCalendar support mobile devices.

- [FullCalendar: Browser Testing & Version Compatibility](https://fullcalendar.io/support)
- [Salesforce: Browser Support for Communities](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_communities_browser_support.htm&type=0)

When I access the community page using a mobile device I am unable to use touch events to create a calendar entry, even though [FullCalendar has Touch Support](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/touch)

Looking in the code, I can see there are `touch` event handlers setup on:

- `document` for `touchstart` and `touchend` and `touchcancel`
- `window` for `touchmove`

These events must be conflicting with the FullCalendar touch events.

Here is an example calendar which can be used to debug:

- [Example Calendar](https://sfse-developer-edition.eu16.force.com/FullCalendar/s/)

It is possible to create events in the calendar when on desktop, but not mobile.

I've tried adding:

```
    document.addEventListener("touchstart", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("touchstart: event.preventDefault()");
    }, false);

    document.addEventListener("touchend", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("touchend: event.preventDefault()");
    }, false);

    document.addEventListener("touchcancel", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("touchcancel: event.preventDefault()");
    }, false);

    window.addEventListener("touchmove", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("touchmove: event.preventDefault()");
    }, false);
```

But I just got this error in the console:

> [Intervention] Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive.

And none of the calendar buttons worked anymore.

**Questions**

Is there any way to remove the Salesforce Communities touch event handlers? or is it impossible due to LockerService?

Any other suggestions regarding how I can get the calendar to work within a Salesforce Community?

---

Cross-posted to:

- [Stackoverflow: How to remove JavaScript touch event handler from document and window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53786269/how-to-remove-javascript-touch-event-handler-from-document-and-window)
- [Salesforce Developer Forums:Is it possible to disable mobile touch on a Salesforce community](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?communityId=09aF00000004HMGIA2#!/feedtype=SINGLE_QUESTION_DETAIL&dc=Developer_Forums&criteria=ALLQUESTIONS&id=9062I000000g50tQAA)

Comment: Did you try to set standardstylesheet to false?

Comment: Are you using it in visualforce or in lightning component?

Comment: @TusharSharma I've updated the question

Comment: We're using fullcalendar.io in a Lightning Community as well, and it works for us. You just have to long press to select a time slot, have you tried that?

Comment: @Folkert have you tried accessing the link in my question via a mobile device?

Comment: Yes, I used your link. Both in Safari and Chrome, you can create an event if you long press.

Comment: @Folkert are you able to create more than one event?

Comment: No, but that's not possible on a desktop either.